# Erro no Docker-Compose.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

Boa noite pessoal, estou com um erro no Docker-compose.yml, o erro apresentado é o seguinte:

[image: Erro]

e o meu código é esse:

```
version: '2.4'
 x-database-variables: &database-variables
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/anime?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql2
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - devdojo_data:/var/lib/mysql
    mem_limit: 512m

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - "./src/main/resources/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
    command: "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    mem_limit: 128m

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    mem_limit: 128m

  springboot2-essentials:
    image: igordmoura/springboot2-essentials:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      <<: *database-variables
    mem_limit: 512m

volumes:
  devdojo_data:
```

Alguem sabe oque está ocasionando este erro?

Desde já agradeço a todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só uma questão de indentação da segunda linha (abaixo de `version: '2.4'`).

Para usar este [YAML anchor](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/) corretamente, basta remover a indentação dele (ficando no mesmo nível de `version`).

O seguinte deve funcionar:

```
version: '2.4'

x-database-variables: &database-variables
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/anime?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql2
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - devdojo_data:/var/lib/mysql
    mem_limit: 512m

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - "./src/main/resources/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
    command: "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    mem_limit: 128m

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    mem_limit: 128m

  springboot2-essentials:
    image: igordmoura/springboot2-essentials:0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      <<: *database-variables
    mem_limit: 512m

volumes:
  devdojo_data:
```